# Illustrator - how do I cut out a shape in text to form one shape and completely remove the cut out

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, shapes, outline

hoping someone can help as this is driving me mad!

I customised some text to add a curve to an A on a logo, I'm in the process of getting some business cards foiled but the cutout is still picking up the same colour and therefore showing on the proof, how do I completely remove this from the shape so that it is not included? I have tried excluding and minus front from the pathfinder and although it removes it, it is still picking up the colour and therefore showing up on the printers proof?

Not sure if I have explained this well but hopefully the images will show you what I mean.... please help![image][image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, can you please try to elaborate a bit further?

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure how best to explain it! Basically the inner section of the 'A' (image 2) I have supposedly cut out is still picking up the magenta colour of the shape despite not showing it on screen so when I am sending it off to be printed it is including that cut out to be foiled (as shown in yellow on image 1) - does that make sense?

Comment: There are *most likely* 2 paths for that counter in the A... one as a counter and one as a filled object. Select, hide, then try selecting it again. Chances are you'll pick up the second object that way. Or select the entire work and use Pathfinder > Merge

Comment: This is a guess: Your A doesn't have a hole. It's printed with metallic spot color and nothing in the print process can guess you want a hole. You have layered a no-ink in CMYK shape on the top but print process does nothing because a white no-ink piece needs nothing. You should get a hole with minus front if your A is outlined, not any more text.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to convert your path into a compound path. Select the path and the cutout (make sure the cutout part is above the other shape in the layers panel) and then *Right Click → Make Compound Path* (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd>)

---

I found this pretty nice article explaining compound paths

https://www.webdesign.org/vector-graphics/adobe-illustrator/compound-paths.12810.html

<sup>(note, I'm not affiliated with this, just a nice resource)</sup>